# Permissions problem after saving file from Mac

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

We use an Ubuntu 14.04 server as file server in our closed network. We use apple and windows workstations (SMB protocol). Sometimes we get problems when saving files to the server like 'Could not save "file name" because write access was not granted'. This is strange since all files and folders have the login in user as owner and 755 permissions. After checking such a file it has 764 rights (rwxrw-r--) and we get this message. Sometimes after multiple safe attempts it works. I run a cronjob now every hour to reset all permissions but it's annoying.

Anyone any advice or tips?

Comment: What is the `create_mask` setting in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` for the particular share?

Comment: [data]
path = /var/datamap
comment = No comment
valid users = skitter
directory mask = 0774
create mode = 0774
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
public = no
printable = no
locking = no
strict locking = no

So I see there this is not correct, thx for this.. But nevertheless this also should not give problems like we have right?

Comment: @user3049694 Please add the details directly [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/830272/edit) rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following directive in your [data] section:

```
force create mode = 755
```

This ensures the minimal level of mode when creating a file.

From the [Samba manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html):

> This parameter specifies a set of UNIX mode bit permissions that will
>   always be set on a file created by Samba. This is done by bitwise
>   'OR'ing these bits onto the mode bits of a file that is being created.
>   The default for this parameter is (in octal) 000. The modes in this
>   parameter are bitwise 'OR'ed onto the file mode after the mask set in the 
>   create mask parameter is applied.